# How to cast with a class reference containing the type of some frame (Delphi)

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I have an application to implement CRUD on many tables.

The main form has a tab for each table and a single toolbar with Insert, Update, Delete buttons valid for all tabs.

Every time the tab is changed, a variable
`frameClass: TFrameClass;` (where `TFrameClass = class of TFrame`) gets the type of frame created under the tab, and other variable `frame: TFrame;` gets the frame created under the tab.

When, say, the INSERT button is clicked, I would like to direct to the `Insert()` procedure corresponding to the active tab, like:

```pascal
frameClass(frame).insert    // trying to cast
```

But the compiler says insert is not a valid method. But if I cast with the content of frameClass, it works:

```pascal
TFrame1(frame).insert;    // does not work in general case.
```

What am I doing wrong?

This is the sample code:

**Unit1.pas**

```
unit unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.Menus,
  FMX.TabControl,
  unit2, unit3;

type
  TFrameClass = class of TFrame;

  TFormMain = class(TForm)
    TabControl1: TTabControl;
    TabItem1: TTabItem;
    TabItem2: TTabItem;
    PopupMenu1: TPopupMenu;
    MenuItemInsert: TMenuItem;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure TabControl1Change(Sender: TObject);
    procedure MenuItemInsertClick(Sender: TObject);
  public
    frame: TFrame;
    frameClass: TFrameClass;
    frames: array[0..1] of TFrameClass;
  end;

var
  FormMain: TFormMain;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TFormMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  frames[0]:= TFrame1;
  frames[1]:= TFrame2;
end;

procedure TFormMain.MenuItemInsertClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // want the insert click to work whatever the activeTab is
  // (frame as FrameClass).insert;   // insert is not a method
  // THIS IS THE GIST OF MY QUESTION:
  // TFrame1(frame).insert;          // it works but want it general
  // FrameClass(frame).insert;       // this is how I'd like it to work
end;

procedure TFormMain.TabControl1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  frameClass:= frames[tabControl1.tabIndex];
  frame:= frameClass.Create(tabControl1.activeTab);
  frame.Parent:= tabControl1.activeTab;end;    
end.
```

**Unit2.pas**

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants, 
  FMX.Types, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.StdCtrls,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation;

type
// if try to descend from other than TFrame, some properties like align, size, etc, are lost
  TFrame1 = class(TFrame)
    Label1: TLabel;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    procedure insert;
  end;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TFrame1.insert;
begin
  //
end;

end.
```

**unit3.pas**

```
unit Unit3;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants, 
  FMX.Types, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.StdCtrls,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.Edit;

type
  // if try to descend from other than TFrame, some properties like align, size, etc, are lost
  TFrame2 = class(TFrame)
    Edit1: TEdit;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    procedure insert;
  end;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TFrame2.insert;
begin
  //
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work the way you want because the base class `TFrame` doesn't have the methods you are looking for, only your derived frame classes do.  When you access a `TFrame` object via the `TFrameClass` class reference (or a base `TFrame` object pointer), you can only access methods that are in `TFrame` itself.  To access derived class methods, you would need to do something more like this:

```pascal
if frame is TFrame1 then
  TFrame1(frame).insert  
else if frame is TFrame2 then
  TFrame2(frame).insert;
```

Which defeats what you are trying to accomplish.  For that, you need to have your frame classes derive from a common ancestor that declares the methods you want, and then you can access those methods via that ancestor when needed.

There are two ways you can do this:

1. create a new base class derived from `TFrame` and has your desired methods, and then change your frame classes to derive from that base.

**Unit1.pas**

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.Menus,
  FMX.TabControl,
  MyFrameBase;

type
  TMyFrameBaseClass = class of TMyFrameBase;

  TFormMain = class(TForm)
    TabControl1: TTabControl;
    TabItem1: TTabItem;
    TabItem2: TTabItem;
    PopupMenu1: TPopupMenu;
    MenuItemInsert: TMenuItem;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure TabControl1Change(Sender: TObject);
    procedure MenuItemInsertClick(Sender: TObject);
  public
    frame: TMyFrameBase;
    frames: array[0..1] of TMyFrameBaseClass;
  end;

var
  FormMain: TFormMain;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

uses
  Unit2, Unit3;

procedure TFormMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  frames[0] := TFrame1;
  frames[1] := TFrame2;
end;

procedure TFormMain.MenuItemInsertClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  frame.Insert;
end;

procedure TFormMain.TabControl1Change(Sender: TObject);
var
  frameClass: TMyFrameBaseClass;
begin
  frameClass := frames[TabControl1.TabIndex];
  frame := frameClass.Create(TabControl1.ActiveTab);
  frame.Parent := TabControl1.ActiveTab;
end;    

end.
```

**MyFrameBase.pas**

```
unit MyFrameBase;

interface

uses
  FMX.Forms;

type
  TMyFrameBase = class(TFrame)
  public
    procedure Insert; virtual; abstract;
  end;

implementation

end.
```

**Unit2.pas**

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants, 
  FMX.Types, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.StdCtrls,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation,
  MyFrameBase;

type
  TFrame1 = class(TMyFrameBase)
    Label1: TLabel;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    procedure Insert; override;
  end;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TFrame1.Insert;
begin
  //
end;

end.
```

**Unit3.pas**

```
unit Unit3;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants, 
  FMX.Types, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.StdCtrls,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.Edit,
  MyFrameBase;

type
  TFrame2 = class(TMyFrameBase)
    Edit1: TEdit;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    procedure Insert; override;
  end;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TFrame2.Insert;
begin
  //
end;

end.
```

2. declare an `interface` that has your desired methods, and then have your frame classes implement that interface.  You can query a frame object for that interface when needed.

**Unit1.pas**

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.Menus,
  FMX.TabControl;

type
  TFrameClass = class of TFrame;

  TFormMain = class(TForm)
    TabControl1: TTabControl;
    TabItem1: TTabItem;
    TabItem2: TTabItem;
    PopupMenu1: TPopupMenu;
    MenuItemInsert: TMenuItem;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure TabControl1Change(Sender: TObject);
    procedure MenuItemInsertClick(Sender: TObject);
  public
    frame: TFrame;
    frames: array[0..1] of TFrameClass;
  end;

var
  FormMain: TFormMain;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

uses
  MyFrameIntf, Unit2, Unit3;

procedure TFormMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  frames[0] := TFrame1;
  frames[1] := TFrame2;
end;

procedure TFormMain.MenuItemInsertClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  intf: IMyFrameIntf;
begin
  if Supports(frame, IMyFrameIntf, intf) then
    intf.Insert;
end;

procedure TFormMain.TabControl1Change(Sender: TObject);
var
  frameClass: TFrameClass;
begin
  frameClass := frames[TabControl1.TabIndex];
  frame := frameClass.Create(TabControl1.ActiveTab);
  frame.Parent := TabControl1.ActiveTab;
end;    

end.
```

**MyFrameIntf.pas**

```
unit MyFrameIntf;

interface

type
  IMyFrameIntf = interface
    ['{83A4D2BF-C72F-4075-9450-4A1480A674A4}']
    procedure Insert;
  end;

implementation

end.
```

**Unit2.pas**

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants, 
  FMX.Types, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.StdCtrls,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation,
  MyFrameIntf;

type
  TFrame1 = class(TFrame, IMyFrameIntf)
    Label1: TLabel;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    procedure Insert;
  end;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TFrame1.Insert;
begin
  //
end;

end.
```

**Unit3.pas**

```
unit Unit3;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants, 
  FMX.Types, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.StdCtrls,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.Edit,
  MyFrameBase;

type
  TFrame2 = class(TFrame, IMyFrameIntf)
    Edit1: TEdit;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    procedure Insert;
  end;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TFrame2.Insert;
begin
  //
end;

end.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Remy! Alternative 1 does not work for me. Every time I tried "TFrame1 = class(different from TFrame)", the frame looses several properties like Align, Size, etc when the frame is closed and reopened. I don´t know if there is a bug in my 10.2 Delphi.

Comment: That definitely sounds like a bug that you should [report to Embarcadero](https://quality.embarcadero.com), because inheritance should not be losing properties like that, so I suspect it will be a bug in the IDE itself, or in the RTTI generated (which has been known to plague recent versions).

Comment: Still, it'd be  nice to cast using a class reference so there is no need of interface or  ` if frame is TFrame1 then
  TFrame1(frame).insert  
else if frame is TFrame2 then
  TFrame2(frame).insert;`. What's wrong with my assumption that frame points to frame created in the active tab and then casting with frameClass tells the layout to interpret it?

Comment: "*it'd be nice to cast using a class reference ... What's wrong with my assumption that ... casting with frameClass tells the layout to interpret it?*" - sorry, but this simply can't be solved that way, that is not how class references work. Casts need to be known at compile-time, not at run-time. You can use a class reference to create an object, but not to cast an object.

Answer (score 0):

Create your base class (with the additional functions that you want) from New Items dialog, Delphi Projects|Delphi File|VCL Frame, as now.
[image: Base Frame]
But then develop all your other frames from that base one you created by selecting from the New Items dialog Delphi Project|**Inheritable Items**|Your base dialog (which will have been added to this page).
[image]
Note that this is not really any different from Remy's first solution, but it explains how in practice you might do it. You are obviously doing something wrong in trying to follow Remy's instructions.